# RxJs globalState from different pipes

Tags: rxjs

I need to have different chains of pipes/branches to be able to modify one global state.

How can I avoid bubbling up global state change event when inside branches?

How can I improve this approach to idiomatic RxJS

````js
const globalState = {}

const br_one_step1$ = globalStateChange$.map(modGlobState_br_one_step1)
const br_one_step2$ = br_one_step1$.map(modGlobState_br_one_step2)
const br_one_step3$ = br_one_step2$.map(modGlobState_br_one_step3)
br_one_step3$.subscribe()

const br_two_step1$ = globalStateChange$.map(modGlobState_br_two_step1)
const br_two_step2$ = br_two_step1$.map(modGlobState_br_two_step2)
const br_two_step3$ = br_two_step2$.map(modGlobState_br_two_step3)
br_two_step3$.subscribe()```
````

Comment: It is a bit confusing about our demo code here. what are those step methods trying to do  ? and what kinda bubbling you talking about

Comment: You might want to check out [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/)